# Error "Attempted relative import" on Sphinx-doc

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-sphinx

I tried to use the autodocumentation of Sphinx-doc. I want to fix the following problem. At the moment, no solutions from StackOverflow worked.
Is it due to the structure of my project or the way I chose to import my modules ?

Given structure of files :

```
project
 |_ src
 |   |_ pre_processing
 |   |     |_ fileInfo.py
 |   |
 |   |_ utils
 |         |_ folder.py
 |_ test
 |      
 |_ doc
 |   |_ doc_user
 |        |_ build
 |        |_ source
 |             |_config.py
```

Following config sys.path :

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../../src/'))
```

I've got some relative imports in fileInfo.py as :

```
from ..utils.folder import get_files_directory
```

Terminal error

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'pre_processing.fileInfo'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/florian-stage/miniconda/envs/gd/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc/importer.py", line 140, in import_module
__import__(modname)

File "/home/florian-stage/Projet-2018/pg_georef_data-master/arbo propre/src/pre_processing/fileInfo.py", line 12, in <module>
from ..utils.folder import get_files_directory
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: Relative imports work in packages. You don't seem to have any package there (no *\_\_init\_\_.py(c)* file present).

Comment: I thought with Python 3.*  we don't need it ?

Comment: Do you name your Sphinx configuration file `config.py`? Normally the name is `conf.py`. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html.

Comment: is this solved? it seems adding __init__ wont get the problem solved

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but, Could you solve it?

If someone has an issue with Sphinx and relative imports too, I recomend try this (following the initial example of this question):

1. Replace at config.py:

> sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../../src/'))

with

> sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../../'))

2. You must change your .rst files if you are using autodoc, for example:

> .. automodule:: pre_processing.fileInfo

with:

> .. automodule:: src.pre_processing.fileInfo

Note: It isn't necessary to create __init__.py files as I could read at previous answers.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your issue has to do with the structure of your project. As [CristiFati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4788546/cristifati) suggested, you should have `__init__.py` files in each of your folders, including `project`. [The docs on packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) deem this necessary:

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path.

For testing your code you'll need to run from some `main.py` file, since imports will be relative to the top-level folder (`project` in this case). Here's how the file structure should look:

```
project
 |  __init__.py
 |  main.py
 |_ src
 |   |  __init__.py
 |   |_ pre_processing
 |   |     |  __init__.py
 |   |     |  fileInfo.py
 |   |
 |   |_ utils
 |         |  __init__.py
 |         |  folder.py
 |_ test
 |   |  __init__.py
 |      
 |_ doc
 |   |  __init__.py
 |   |_ doc_user
 |        |  __init__.py
 |        |_ build
 |             |  __init__.py
 |        |_ source
 |             |  __init__.py
 |             |  config.py
```

Then in `main.py` you should have:

```
from src.pre_processing import fileInfo
```

Running `main.py` should now produce error-free output.

Comment: There is no point in adding `__init__.py` files in the doc directory, assuming that it contains a Sphinx project. A Sphinx project has a conf.py file but does not need any `__init__.py` files.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the **project root instead of the source directory** to the sys.path seems to resolve the issue. Keep in mind to add `__init__.py` files to declare packages.

Afterwards you should also modify the references to modules in your `*.rst` files, prepending `src`.

### Examples:

```
#  in "doc/doc_user/source/config.py"
import os
# ("../../..") instead of ("../../../src")!
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../.."))
```

Sample definition in `__init__.py`

```
#  in "src/utils/__init__.py"
from .folder import get_files_directory
```

Import in fileInfo. May vary depending how or if you imported `get_files_directory` into `__init__.py` at all.

```
# in "src/pre_processing/fileInfo.py"
from ..utils import get_files_directory
```

Reference in any `*.rst` file should look something like this. (Prepending `src`)

```
.. automodule:: src.pre_processing.fileInfo
  :members:
```

```
project
 ├── src
 │   ├── __init__.py
 │   ├── ...
 │   ├── pre_processing
 │        ├── __init__.py
 │        ├── fileInfo.py
 │   └── utils
 │        ├── __init__.py
 │        └── folder.py
 ├── test
 ├── doc
 │   └── doc_user
 │        ├── build
 │        └── source
 │             ├── config.py
 │             └── ...
```

Another example using a single directory for sphinx documentation.

```
#  in "docs/conf.py"
import os
# ("..") instead of ("../src")!
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))
```

```
project
 ├── src
 ├── test
 ├── docs
 │    ├── _static
 │    ├── _templates
 │    ├── ...
 │    ├── index.rst
 │    └── conf.py
 ├── ...
 ├── setup.cfg
 └── setup.py
```

### References

1. [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)
2. [Python Modules and Packages – An Introduction](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/)
3. [Implicit Namespace Packages](https://newbedev.com/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3)