# Relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, python-sphinx, relative-import

After many searches and attempts I have not found a solution to this problem...

I am using Sphinx to generate documentation for a Python package.
You can see the code here: https://github.com/jajimer/energym/tree/documentation. The part of the package we are interested in is organized as follows:

[image: Folder structure]

In `energym/docs/source/conf.py` I have configured the path as follows:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../energym/'))
```

And now I'm trying to add to the API documentation (`energym/doc/source/pages/API-reference.rst`) the description of this `utils` module and all its components. For this, I am using Sphinx's `autosummary`:

```
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: modules
   :template: custom-module-template.rst
   :recursive:
   
   utils
```

So, after doing `make clean && make html`, the documentation for `utils.common`, `utils.rewards` and `utils.rewards` is perfectly created, but not for `utils.controllers`. According to Sphinx, the following exception occurs:

```
File "/home/user/projects/energym/energym/utils/controllers.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..utils.common import parse_variables
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

And here is my question. How can I fix it? Is it a relative path problem? I've seen that the problem is due to the following import:

```
from ..utils.common import parse_variables
```

But I don't really know the reason, as the path seems to be perfectly set.

Comment: Solved here https://stackoverflow.com/q/50413824

Comment: Try `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))`. It looks like you went one level too far up the directory tree.

Comment: Using `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))` and adding `energym.utils` to `autosummary` worked perfectly! Thanks!!